# Make Xcode (swift )throw error for print()

Tags: xcode, swift, compiler-warnings

I created a custom Logger for logging values for different modes like debug, release but I want that whenever I use the default `print()` Xcode should throw an error explaining the user to use the custom logger.

I referred [this](http://jeffreysambells.com/2013/01/31/generate-xcode-warnings-from-todo-comments) but want to throw error there and then rather than adding a build-phase.

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could shadow the built-in `print` in your module and mark it "unavailable":

```
// swift 3:
@available(*, unavailable, message: "use Logger instead!")
internal func print(_ items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {
    Swift.print(items, separator: separator, terminator: terminator)
}

// swift 2:
@available(*, unavailable, message="use Logger instead!")
internal func print(items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {
    Swift.print(items, separator: separator, terminator: terminator)
}
```

The result looks like:

[image: Xcode errors]

(There is still another instance of `print<Target>(..., to output: inout Target)` which I don't bother to hide, I guess no one will accidentally use that function.)

As shown, you could still use the qualified name `Swift.print` to refer to the real function in case of emergency.

Note that this will only affect **your own module**. You can't force users outside of your module to not use `print`.

Comment: kennytm:   Thanks.. Thats Perfect!